# Why csv data loads to only to the first column of hive table?

Tags: csv, hive, hdfs

I uploaded a csv with the following data:

[image: this is my data in CSV]

following are the commands that I used to upload the data to hive

1. Drag the file to linux file system.
2. Use the following command to upload to hdfs.
   hadoop fs -put "/home/kdeep/kd_city_data.csv" /home/kdeep
3. Use hive to load the data
   load data inpath '/home/kdeep' into table dev.k_site;

My table looks like this:
[image: Table]

Comment: Looks like a dodgy delimiter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do create the table? you must specify the delimiter :

hive> CREATE TABLE dev.k_site(String Location,Year String,perc_food double,perc_g double) row format delimited fields terminated by ‘,’ ;

Comment: this should have solved the problem. However, it is not working.

Comment: It actually solved the problem. I don't know why it was not working the other day. Thanks.

Comment: I had this same issue. including the part about the solution not fixing the problem. For me, I was confirming the change via impala (not hive directly) This led to the table defn still not being right. then from impala you have to: invalidate metadata TABLE_NAME; & execute refresh TABLE_NAME;